# I can't get my data from my document with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, single-page-application

I'm creating a single page application with javascript by using the firebase firestore as database.
I've managed to get all my documents listed where I call for all of them. Each document has an href to the detail page. But on the detailpage, it looks like I don't have any data from my document.
I want to call the title from the document to show as an h1 but noting renders and I don't have any errors in my console..

Anyone who can help me?

My code:
This is to get all the documents (who are events)

```
// Get events

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const Events = {
  getAll: async () => {
    // get firestore
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    // define query
    const query = db.collection('events');

    // query snapshot
    const querySnapshot = await query.get();

    // loop over all documents
    return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => (
      {
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      }
    ));
  },

  // get the data from a detailpage by the ID
  getById: async (id) => {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const event = await (await (db.collection('events').doc(id).get())).data();
    return event;
  },

};

export default Events;
```

My component to render all documents as a list

```
import Component from '../lib/Component';
import Elements from '../lib/Elements';
import Router from '../Router';
import Events from '../lib/Events';

class EventsComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super({
      name: 'events',
      model: {
        events: [],
      },
      routerPath: '/events',
    });
    this.eventsLoaded = false;
  }

  // Get the events one by one, make them an href to their detail page and show the name of the 
     event
  loadEvents() {
    if (!this.eventsLoaded) {
      Events.getAll().then((data) => {
        this.model.events = data.map((event) => ({
          href: `${Router.getRouter().link('/event')}/${event.id}`,
          textContent: event.title,
        }));
      });
      this.eventsLoaded = true;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { events } = this.model;

    // create home container
    const eventsContainer = document.createElement('div');

    // Load events
    this.loadEvents();

    // Check if there are any events
    if (events.length === 0) {
      eventsContainer.innerHTML = 'There are no events planned at the moment';
    } else {
      eventsContainer.appendChild(
        Elements.createList({
          items: this.model.events,
        }),
      );
    }

    return eventsContainer;
  }
}

export default EventsComponent;
```

My detail page

```
// Event Component

import Component from '../lib/Component';
import Elements from '../lib/Elements';
import Events from '../lib/Events';

class EventComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super({
      name: 'event',
      model: {
        event: [],
      },
      routerPath: '/event/:id',
    });
    this.eventLoaded = false;
  }

  // Set the model loading to true when the id page is founded
  loadEvent(id) {
    if (!this.eventLoaded) {
      this.eventLoaded = true;
      Events.getById(id).then((data) => {
        this.model.event = data;
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { event } = this.model;

    // create event overview container
    const eventContainer = document.createElement('div');

    // Check for existing events and return the events.
    // Create an h1 with the name of the event as title
    if (!event) {
      this.loadEvent(this.props.id);
    } else {
      eventContainer.appendChild(
        Elements.createHeader({
          textContent: event.title,
        }),
      );
      console.log(this.model.event);
    }
    return eventContainer;
  }
}

export default EventComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have model set as an array insted of an object in you detail page.

```
constructor() {
    super({
      name: 'event',
      model: {
        event: [],
      },
      routerPath: '/event/:id',
    });
    this.eventLoaded = false;
  }
```

When you try to access your event you are trying to get .title from an array insted of an object.

```
 Elements.createHeader({
          textContent: event.title,
        }),
```

I would map the event field by field { "field" : 0, "field2": ""} but you may find a way to make it less verbose

Comment: Should I set my model as an object instead of an array?

Comment: Yes. 
Or access the first position of the array like event[0].title 
But your getById return a single object, so i would guess that your array is not even populated.

Comment: Try with 
 model: {
        event: {},
      }
may solve the problem.

Comment: Only in your detail page ofc, your list page should keep the array

Comment: I changed it but nothing happens..

Comment: A console.log to take a look what is in my model returns the keyword "object" with no further data

Comment: Have you tried pushing the response from your getById  into the array and then reading the array? Instead of asignation with "=" operator

Comment: Still nothin happens..